# Replace version in multiline string

Tags: regex, kotlin, multiline

I'm trying to replace the version of a chart name in a file and have constructed the following trimmed down example. But nothing gets replaced. Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

```
val content = """releases:
  web-env:
    version: 1.7.0
    enabled: true
  web-app:
    enabled: true
    version: 1.39.0
"""

val chart = "web-env"
val version = "new version"

val regex = "($chart:.*version: )(.*)\n".toRegex(MULTILINE)
val replace = content.replaceFirst(regex, "$1$version")
println(replace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MULTILINE` in the code is giving error and not working. May be its because of some missing import but I have no knowledge of Kotlin at all. But seems like that `MULTILINE` is like `DOTALL` to enable dot matching newlines too. The `.*` in your regex is greedy so even if I make your regex work, it will replace the second version in your text, hence you should use non-greedy version in your regex `[\\w\\W]*?` and `\\S+` matches one or more non-space characters and will match `1.7.0` although you can even write it as `\\d+(\\.\\d+)*` if you want to be precisely matching only digit version.

I have removed `MULTILINE` from your code and corrected regex, which seems to be working fine. Check out this modified code,

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val content = """releases:
      web-env:
        version: 1.7.0
        enabled: true
      web-app:
        enabled: true
        version: 1.39.0
    """

    val chart = "web-env"
    val version = "new version"

    val regex = "($chart:[\\w\\W]*?version: )(\\S+)".toRegex()
    val replace = content.replaceFirst(regex, "$1$version")
    println(replace)
}
```

Note: `[\\w\\W]` is another way to enable matching any character including newline.

This prints following output which is what I guess you expect,

```
releases:
      web-env:
        version: new version
        enabled: true
      web-app:
        enabled: true
        version: 1.39.0
```

**[Kotlin Code Demo](https://pl.kotl.in/rJ6loU4UN)**

Hope this works fine and let me know for any issues.

Comment: val regex = "(?s)($chart:.*?version: )(.*?)\n".toRegex(MULTILINE) - Works as well. But thanks for answering. Any comments on which is to be preferred?

Comment: @user672009: You can use either. Both are just two ways of achieving same thing.

Comment: However, performance wise this `(web-env:\s+version: )(\S+)` is better [Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/hEmgYW/3) (30 steps) than `(web-env.*?version: )(.*?)\n` [Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/hEmgYW/2) (50 steps)